# How to solve ODE: $\frac{dy}{dt} - 2ty = -3t^2e^{t^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve first order ODE: $\frac{dy}{dt} - 2ty = -3t^2e^{t^2}$. I tried using substitution $t^{2} = u$, but after substitution I get $\frac{dy}{dt} - y\frac{du}{dt} = -3ue^u$, which I am unable to solve.

Comment: No substitution is needed ! It's a very classical ODE. First solve the homogeneous equation and then, use [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters)

Comment: Introduce an integrating factor on the left hand side to write it as $\frac{d}{dt}\left[ye^{-t^2}\right] = -3t^2$. Now just integrate.

Comment: You can use this formula here: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html

Comment: Your substitution is wrong, too: if you do a change of variable $t^2=u$, there is no $t$ in the new equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Integration Factor

To begin to answer your question one can observe that this problem is easily solved using an integration factor.

\begin{equation}\frac{dy}{dt} - 2ty = -3t^2e^{t^2} \end{equation}
Then I would state the following: \begin{align}\mu(x)&=e^{P(x)}\\ &=e^{\int -2t\ dt}\\&= e^{-t^2} \end{align}
Then using this integrating factor I would multiply through the DE to solve it, and observe something neat happens.
\begin{align}e^{-t^2}\frac{dy}{dt}-2te^{t^2}y&=-3t^2\\ \frac{dy}{dt}\Bigg[ye^{-t^2}\Bigg]&=-3t^2\\ ye^{-t^2}&=-t^3+C \\ y&=Ce^{t^2}-t^3e^{t^2}\end{align}

Comment: (+1) However, since there may be other ways to solve a problem, I would use "one *can* observe" rather than "one *has to* observe".